# Seeking a forum with post-specific screen names and flairs

Tags: web-apps, forum

I would like a board that can support a few hard to get features:

1. Dynamic screen names and other local flairs that a person can use specific to a post certainly represent the highest priority
2. I would like a way to let a top forum include the subforums' content and/or a system allowing tag forums the way http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/ can
3. Hierarchical reply structures similar to reddit and slashdot would be a help but I would prefer a forum specific option to use these or the flat way forums commonly employ

There is not a board out there with all of these I think?

Comment: You want to self-host this, right? Does it have to be in PHP?

Comment: I would take a board on any language or server though self is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Xenforo](http://xenforo.com)

- Flairs, user titles, badges.
- Excellent Sub forums system
- Fantastic moderation/administration tools.
- Real time alerts system
- Wonderful conversation system (PM) *supports multiple users in one conversation*
- Lots and lots of add-ons
- Recent activity stream
- Usernames can be styled with CSS styling.
- Responsive design
- Great report and warning system
- Post edit history
- Groups

and way more!

Comment: I did try a trial there but could not find anything related to the 3 features.